# Cast records to columns with grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query from my SQL Server database :

```
Date        Type        Amount  
1392/06/21  Ticket      1350000    
1392/06/22  Free        9650000  
1392/06/22  Market      10820000  
1392/06/22  Ticket      1050000  
1392/06/21  Market      10040000  
1392/06/20  Free        11750000  
1392/06/20  Ticket      960000  
1392/06/21  Free        13050000  
1392/06/20  Market      9220000
```

and I want to cast it to this one :

```
Date            Ticket      Free        Market  
1392/06/20      960000      11750000    9220000  
1392/06/21      1350000     13050000    10040000  
1392/06/22      1050000     9650000     10820000
```

The only solution I can think of that does not take a long time is to read the first query to my .net application and then group it there using `foreach` loop, but I would rather to learn the basic solution that T-SQL provides.

Does anyone have any clue to do so in T-SQL ?

Comment: Take a look at TSQL Pivot command: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @YuriyGalanter that's exactly what I need, thanks. I'm following the link. If you put the answer below I'll accept it so that other users having the same question can check the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to the Pivot command you can do:

```
SELECT Date, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Ticket' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Ticket,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Market' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Market,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Free' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Free
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Date
```

Answer (score 3):

What are you dealing with is a classic case for TSQL Pivot command.

Please take a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Sorry I can't accept a link as an answer, please provide the full code and I'll answer it. Thanks.

Comment: Um... do a little research on your own?

Comment: If you're still having problems, I will update the answer with code a bit later, currently kinda pressed for time.

Comment: I did research and I got the answer, but I cannot accept a link, sorry I'll have to accept the other answer as long as it has code.

Comment: (Note to self) Only answers with explicit code solution (no code explanation required) are deemed worthy of acceptance. Simple pointing to the right direction, providing information doesn't count. Thanks for the pointers, that should provide helpful in the future.

Comment: Another note: I did put the link initially as a comment only. You were the one who asked to put it as an answer.

Comment: I've upvoted this.  While I dislike the native Pivot command (I always found its syntax needlessly bizarre), this is a valid answer.

Comment: @Aushin Thanks. yup. syntax does look strange, especially when u use it for the 1st time. But it gets the job done, and imo more flexible that multiple case statements.